# German resources loaded from resource only dll when system locale is french

Tags: c++, mfc, internationalization, resource-files

In an MFC application, there are **German, French, Spanish** resource files. These resource files have resources to be loaded for all sub-languages.

Say for German:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEU) || defined(AFX_TARG_DES) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEA) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEL) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEC)
LANGUAGE LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
#pragma code_page(1252)
```

Resource DLL is loaded using `LoadLibrary`. OS is Windows 7 Enterprise English version. In clock -> language -> region from Control Panel, it is "France".
What is the reason for German resources to be loaded when MFC application is opened?

Comment: maybe you set a priority or something similar.

Comment: Any idea how to set priority?

Comment: see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx)

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. I used setlocale which loaded the proper resources from resource only dll.

Comment: OK i add this as a answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discuss in comments you can use `setlocale` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx) is the solution.